# How whenever gem use in rails for cronjob processing?

Tags: whenever

How should we use whenever gem in rails 3 for cronjob processing? i have one rake task which i need to run after every 5 min ,how can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

Go through below link which explains how to configure and use.

https://github.com/javan/whenever

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

As per your question below is the code that runs rake task every 5 minutes. This should be in `config/schedule.rb` file

```
every 5.minutes do    
  rake "your_task" or "namespace:your_task"
end
```